# UIButton border disappears when zoomIn on a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a `UIScrollview` on which there is a `UIImageView`, on `imageview` i  have multiple `UIButtons` which are selectable.

The number of buttons on the view is dynamic and hence it can be in any number. When this count is more we are facing an issue where the border of the button is disappearing. If we zoom out we can see the border of the button. Please see the attached screen for more information.

Please help in resolving this problem!

[image: Button Border Problem]

Comment: are you seeing this on simulator?

Comment: try it in real iPad ,the  simulator has less pixels and can't show borders sometime.

Comment: The screenshot i have pasted here is from simulator Fahim Parkar i am having this problem even on device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the simulator with a scale that is lower than 100% you can sometimes see distortion on rendered objects. If you are using the simulator with a scale lower than 100% then try changing it to 100% (In the Simulator menu bar: Window>Scale>100%). This should show your objects the way you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks user444333222!

I agree on that, i am facing this problem on device too. Even i can see this border problem when simulator is made 100%. Any help please let me know